# Как из списка достать value? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Из этого списка мне надо достать значение "value":2.5 и чтобы была только цифра, тобишь 2.5.

```
{"sensors":[{"id":8450,"type":1,"value":2.5,"time":1618328421,"changed":1618328421,"trend":0}]}
```

помогите пожайлуста :)

Comment: В учебниках уже не пишут, как из списка и словаря брать элементы?

Comment: Сначала у того словаря обратитесь по ключу `"sensors"`, из значения обратитесь к значению по `0` индексу, а у него обратитесь по ключу `"value"`. Это будет серия вызова через квадратные скобки

Comment: я по учебнику выучил только поверхностный синтаксис и сразу пошел делать кое-что :).

Comment: @gil9red, а как это в коде будет?

Comment: `d['sensors'][0]['value']`

Comment: @entithat спасибо

Comment: @gil9red спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, что данный объект хранится в переменной `result`
Сначала получаем значения ключа `sensors`, там мы видим массив. Соответственно, нужно достать объект из массива, в нашем случае достаем первый. Далее достаем значение `value`

`result['sensors'][0]['value']` выдаст нужный вам результат

Comment: @Shellarб спасибо

Comment: выдает ошибку 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @СашаГоголь `response.json()['sensors'][0]['value']` может тогда

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо)